# JQuery auto complete from XML

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, search, jquery-autocomplete

I'm playing around with jquery ui autocomplete. And have a question about how to query the XML data. I have an XML file with a list of locations, similar to:

```
<geoname>
    <name_en>The Tower of London</name_en>
    <name_fr>Example text</name_fr>
    <lat>51.5082349601834</lat>
    <lng>-0.0763034820556641</lng>
    <geonameId>6286786</geonameId>
    <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
    <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>
    <fcl>S</fcl>
    <fcode>CSTL</fcode>
    <web>http://www.exmaple.com</web>
</geoname>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    lang = 'en';        
    $.ajax({
        url: "places.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function( xmlResponse ) {
            var data = $( "countryCode", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: $( "name", this ).text(),
                    id: $( "geonameId", this ).text(),
                    countryName: $( "countryName", this ).text(),
                    link: $( "web", this ).text(),
                    code: $( "countryCode", this ).text()
                };
            }).get();

            $( "#results" ).autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 0,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                        $('#foo').html('');
                        $('#foo').html(ui.item.code).slideDown();

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What I'm having trouble with is that I want to specify a variable that says only search name_en when I've set it to EN, and in other cases only search for name_fr when set to FR. I don't want name_fr results to come back when I've set the language to EN. Thanks in advance.

Comment: return {
     value: $( "name_fr", this ).text(),

Sorry, got it now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll post the code:

**HTML**

```
<select id="lang">
    <option value="en">EN</option>
    <option value="fr">FR</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="results" />
<span id="foo" />
```

**XML**

```
<list>
<geoname>
    <name_en>The Tower of London</name_en>
    <name_fr>Example text</name_fr>
    <lat>51.5082349601834</lat>
    <lng>-0.0763034820556641</lng>
    <geonameId>6286786</geonameId>
    <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
    <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>
    <fcl>S</fcl>
    <fcode>CSTL</fcode>
    <web>http://www.exmaple.com</web>
</geoname>
<geoname>
    <name_en>En name</name_en>
    <name_fr>Fr name</name_fr>
    <lat>51.5082349601834</lat>
    <lng>-0.0763034820556641</lng>
    <geonameId>6286786</geonameId>
    <countryCode>GB2</countryCode>
    <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>
    <fcl>S</fcl>
    <fcode>CSTL</fcode>
    <web>http://www.exmaple.com</web>
</geoname>
</list>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {       
    var lang = "en";
    $("#lang").bind("change", function() {
        lang = this.value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function( xmlResponse ) {
            var data = $("geoname", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: "",
                    name_en: $( "name_en", this ).text(),
                    name_fr: $("name_fr", this).text(),
                    id: $( "geonameId", this ).text(),
                    countryName: $( "countryName", this ).text(),
                    link: $( "web", this ).text(),
                    code: $( "countryCode", this ).text()
                };
            }).get(); 
            $( "#results" ).autocomplete({
                source: function(req, add) {
                 var source = [];
                 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                 {               
                    if (lang == "en")
                    {
                     data[i].value = data[i].name_en;   
                    }
                    else if (lang == "fr")
                    {
                        data[i].value = data[i].name_fr;  
                    }
                 if (data[i].value.substr(0, req.term.length).toLowerCase() == req.term.toLowerCase())
                 {
                     source.push(data[i]);   
                 }
                 } 
                 add(source);
                },
                minLength: 0,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                        $('#foo').html('');
                        $('#foo').html(ui.item.code).slideDown();

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And here is a **JSFiddle** solution I tested

http://jsfiddle.net/pinusnegra/KFHnd/

It's a little messy, but you can make it better if you want. I tell you how it works:

First, you receive a list of 'geoname' nodes I think, not only one:

```
var data = $("geoname", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: "",
                    name_en: $( "name_en", this ).text(),
                    name_fr: $("name_fr", this).text(),
                    id: $( "geonameId", this ).text(),
                    countryName: $( "countryName", this ).text(),
                    link: $( "web", this ).text(),
                    code: $( "countryCode", this ).text()
                };
            }).get();
```

You get the name_en and name_fr value, and you set the 'value' to an empty string (the 'value' will be the jQuery autocomplete text).

In jQuery autocomplete, you can set a function to the source, which has a 'req' object, and an 'add' callback.

The 'req' object contains a 'term' property, which is the actual textbox input. The 'add' callback adds a list (an array) of the matched items.

So you initialize a 'source' array:

```
source: function(req, add) {
                 var source = [];
```

then you iterate over the 'data' array, and based on the current 'lang', setup the 'value' property with the actual 'name_en' or 'name_fr'.

After this, you can test on the 'object.value', if it's match the requirements:

```
if (data[i].value.substr(0, req.term.length).toLowerCase() == req.term.toLowerCase())
                 {
                     source.push(data[i]);   
                 }
```

if so, then push into the 'source' array.

and...
    add(source);
'returns' the actual list.

Notice that the source function of the autocomplete object will be called everytime when a new autocomplete search occurs, so you return the right collection of items everytime.

Of course, you can make a more sophisticated and optimized solution if this one meets your requirements.

cheers, negra