# Format jquery ui autocomplete xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Need to get my auto suggest values populated within "completion" tag in my "Completions" parent, my alert is working fine and returning the data but i cant get to load it on my auto suggest results....any help would greatly appreciated.

This is my xml sctucture:

```
     <Completions>
<Term>maz</Term>
<Completion profile="test">mazda</Completion>
<Completion profile="test">mazdak</Completion>
<Completion profile="test">maza</Completion>
<Completion profile="test">maz</Completion>
<Completion profile="test">mzx</Completion>
</Completions>

<script>
    $(function() {
    // add autocomplete
    $("#query.queryAutocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var myArr = [];
            $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "searchlogic.asp",
             //complete: setupAC,
             contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: 'xml',
                data: {             
                    pr: $("input[name='pr']").val(),
                    term: request.term              

                },          
                //success: function( data ) {
                   // alert(data);
                  //},

                  success: function(responseXML) {
            alert($(responseXML).text());
       },




    error: function(e) {
       alert(e.message);
    }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
         open: function (e, ui) {
            var term = $("#query").val();

            var acData = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete");
            acData.menu.element.find("a").each(function () {
                var a = $(this);
                var completion = a.text().substring(term.length);
                a.html("<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>" + term + "</span>" + "<span class='ui-autocomplete-completion'>" + completion + "</span>");
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#query").val(ui.item.value)
                .closest("form").submit();
        },

    });
});
```

```
<input class="queryAutocomplete" id="query" type="textbox" name="query" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="pr" value="test">
<input type="submit" class="searchbutton" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you would need to convert your XML to Html and transform each element to the form

```
<Completion profile="test">whatever</Completion>
```

and after that append them to completions using jQuery append

Example (I used UL and LI instead op Completion to make things vissible )  :

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce3n4/1/)

In your case this would result in something like

```
var newItems = '<Completion profile="test">[new var 1]</Copmletion><Completion profile="test">[new var 2]</Copmletion>';
$("Completions").append(newItems);
```

Id recommend to use and Id on your "Completions" tag to avoid interference with other  sets if there are/will be any.

Comment: i think what I need to do to find the xml tag then parse it, its not just to convert

Comment: Have you read this article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328481/jquery-auto-complete-from-xml

Comment: The data is showing on a div now when i append it but still not on the auto com success: function(responseXML) {
      
                 //($(responseXML).find('Completion').text());
     
     $(responseXML).find("Completions").each(function () {
 
        $(".main").append('<ul><li>' + $(this).find("Completion").text() + '</li></ul>');
        //$(".book").fadeIn(1000);
 
    });
      
                    },

Comment: I used UL and Li in the example, but probably you don't need that in the autocomplete.

Comment: yeah that still doesnt solve the issue, it was for testing only.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.